# How to run a post build action when the build status changed from Stable to Unstable/Fail

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We want to publish some information (time, build no, GIT Author etc.) to confluence when our Jenkins build status change from stable to unstable/failed but not in subsequent consecutive failures.
We tried using flexible publish with conditional actions. But conditional actions only allow to specify best/worse conditions of current build. There is no way to compare it with the status of previous build.
We would like to use plugins and shell scripts over groovy scripts.